# Need help with level 3 Calculus problem

Tags: calculus, area

> Two curves $$C_1: ([f(y)]^{2/3} + ([f(x)]^{1/3}) = 0\quad\mbox{and}\quad C_2: [f(y)]^{2/3}+ [f(x)]^{2/3} = 12, $$ satisfying the relation $$ (x-y)f(x+y)-(x+y)f(x-y) = 4xy(x^2-y^2).$$
>
> 1.) Evaluate the area bounded by $C_1$ and $C_2$.
>
> 2.) Evaluate the area bounded by $C_2$ and $|x|+|y|=\sqrt{12}$.
>
> 3.) Evaluate the area bounded by $C_1$ and $x+y+2=0$.

It was hard to write math here so:
[Have a look at this pic for clear question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwSLw.jpg)

Comment: Do you know how to approach the question even? Where in particular are you struggling?

Comment: I don't even know how to approach the question. Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Functional Equation : If $(x-y)f(x+y) -(x+y)f(x-y) =4xy(x^2-y^2)$ for all x,y find f(x).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702695/functional-equation-if-x-yfxy-xyfx-y-4xyx2-y2-for-all-x-y-fi)
the general solution of the function equation 
$$(x-y)f(x+y)-(x+y)f(x-y) = 4xy(x^2-y^2)$$
is $f(x)=x^3+kx$ with $k\in\mathbb{R}$. So the problem seems to be ambiguous because $f$ (and therefore also the curves $C_1$ and $C_2$) is not uniquely determined.

Note that if we let $k=0$ then $f(x)=x^3$ and
$$C_1: \; y^2+x=0\quad \mbox{and}\quad C_2:x^2+y^2=12.$$
In this case the area bounded by $C_1$ and $C_2$ is
$$2\int_{-\sqrt{12}}^{-3}\sqrt{12-x^2}dx+2\int_{-3}^0\sqrt{-x}dx=
2\pi+\sqrt{3}.$$